# How to detect if chrome profile is in use chrome driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

We have an internal company utility that can open our internal sites through various browsers using the various browser drivers (iexplore, geckodriver, chromedriver).

One of the options for the chromedriver is to use the profile of logged-in Google users. However, it doesn't work if the profile is already in use from another instance of Chrome.

Anyone know of a way to detect if the profile of the currently logged-in user is in use? Then the utility can just skip adding that option into the list of arguments when we launch a browser.

I know there's a workaround for an individual computer, but as not everyone in the company will know how to set that up, it's okay if the instance doesn't automatically load the Google profile.

Comment: Hello, dennisq. I' guessing, that programmatically, you can check if process is run with profile flag.